# How do I suppress the address bar in mobile Safari?

Tags: mobile-safari, websites

When I add the [Nibbble](http://nial.me/nibbble/app/) web app to my iPhone home page, it not only installs an icon, but when run, also hides all of the mobile Safari chrome.

How does it achieve this?

Comment: Good answer from @zevlag but this probably belongs on StackOverflow.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need the first part of this code to do what you ask, but the rest may also be helpful.

```
// hide the browser chrome
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /> 

//set the phone status bar style; can be grey, black, or black translucent
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

// set the viewport for iOS
<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=0.6667, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />

// set a custom icon for when a user bookmarks the app to the home screen
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/path/to/icon.png" />
```

Comment: Why is ```maximum-scale=0.6667``` ? Don't we need also ```initial-scale=1.0``` here ?